# Excel: Change text color in cells based on input in one cell (incl. updating)

Tags: vba, excel, colors, conditional-formatting

I'm not an expert in Excel or VBA, but I do my best. I have an Excel file where cell D10 is either blank or not blank.

Based on cell D10 being blank or not blank, I want to format the text color and/or cell fill in other cells. Cell D10 can change between being blank and not blank, and the colors have to change accordingly.

First I tried to do this without using VBA:
[image: Conditonal Formatting]

This did not work as I had hoped. The changes did not apply to all cells in the selection, and changing cell D10 from blank to not blank and back to blank did not work.

Then I tried some VBA, which I do not really know how to do. Could someone give me a helping hand?

```
Sub colourChange()

If Range("D10") = ISBLANK Then
    Range("C18:I20").Font.Color = RGB(256, 256, 256)
    Range("C32:I33").Font.Color = RGB(256, 256, 256)
End If

If Range("D10") = Not (ISBLANK) Then
    Range("C18:I20").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Range("C32:I33").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End If

End Sub
```

How do I make this module constantly "on"?

Comment: try the code in my answer below for a VBA solution

Comment: I'm not sure if I got this right. See link to image below. Did I do anything wrong? As I've mentioned earlier, I'm no good at VBA.
[Screenshot](https://s17.postimg.org/azl3ukpin/vba.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select cell D10 and the ribbon go to Formulas > Define Name and give cell D10 a name (for example, I'll use myVal.)

For your first conditional formatting formula rule have:

```
=myVal=""
```

And for your second:

```
=myVal<>""
```

This will check to see if there is any sort of value in D10, and apply the formatting correctly.

I've updated this answer as Excel wasn't cooperating fully with the initial solution I gave, but I believe this should solve it!

Comment: Thank you :). However, this does not work for the entire selection: "=$C$18:$I$20;$C$32:$I$33". Only one cell (C18) changes when D10 is changed. The rest have white text, regardless of D10.

Comment: Change the semi colon to a comma if you want to add an extra range.

Comment: I think my version of Excel uses semi colon instead of comma. At least that's what I have to use in formulas (e.g. =IF(A1=A2;"OK";"Not OK").

Comment: Very odd, I've just noticed this as well! Sorry. A workaround I got is to give D10 a named range. On the formula tab go to define name, and set d10 to any name (let's say myVal.) Then change it so your rules say =myVal="", =myVal<>"".

Comment: Defined names are super useful in Excel, for both formulas and VBA, they'll change your life!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use VBA, you need to move the code to `Worksheet_Change` event of the relevant sheet.

Then, you need to check if the `Target` range is Cell D10, and then check how to modify the `Font.Color` accordingly.

*Note*: you can set multiple ranges in one line with `Union`, as I implemented in my code below.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WatchRange                  As Range

' set watch range to cell D10
Set WatchRange = Range("D10")

' if modifed cell is D10 >> enter the rest of the code
If Not Intersect(Target, WatchRange) Is Nothing Then
    If IsEmpty(Range("D10")) Or Range("D10").Value = "" Then
        Union(Range("C18:I20"), Range("C32:I33")).Font.Color = RGB(256, 256, 256)
    Else
        Union(Range("C18:I20"), Range("C32:I33")).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
End If

End Sub
```